# unity: transaparent android activity showing black background instead?

Tags: android-activity, unity-game-engine, transparent

I am developing a unity plugin that allows showing a new activity on top of the existing unity activity. The new activity is a standard android activity (does not derive from unity activity, etc). The new activity is not full screen, i.e. it is a popup, design to show a transparent background (to be able to see the underlying unity scene). When I run the activity code in a native android app, all is fine, I can see the underlying activity. But when I run it inside a unity app (wrapped by a plugin), the new activity popup UI shows up with black background - the underlying unity scene/activity does not show.

here is the activity definition in the manifest, as you can see it has the usual Translucent values, etc:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="com.mycomp.MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

any ideas why I don't see the background?